# anybadge fails with: cannot import name 'get_template' from 'anybadge.templates'?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'd like to run `anybadge`, but it fails with the following error. Why?

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends python3-pip
- pip3 install anybadge
```

Usage:

```
anybadge --label='mylabel' --value='myvalue' --file='my.svg' --color=yellow
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/anybadge", line 5, in <module>
    from anybadge.cli import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anybadge/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .badge import Badge
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anybadge/badge.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .templates import get_template
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_template' from 'anybadge.templates' (unknown location)
```

Comment: The issues is closed, so I'm voting to close this question as this was a very temporary problem.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the version of `anybadge` that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue, somehow an anybadge update is causing the problem: https://github.com/jongracecox/anybadge/issues/63